# how to remove duplicate elements from the linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have to make a program to count the number of occurrences of a given key in a singly linked
list  and  then  delete  all  the  occurrences.  For  example,  if  given  linked  list  is  1->2->1->2->1->3->1  and  given  key  is  1,  then  output  should  be  4.  After  deletion  of  all  the
occurrences of 1, the linked list is 2->2->3.

I tried making a program that removes duplicate elements from a linked list and count the number of occurrence of the duplicate element
output for my program is

```
Your linked list is 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 
Enter a number: 1
Number of occurance is: 4
After deleting repeated elements: 
Your linked list is 2 2 1 3 1
```

I am going to add third case to remove element from the end soon but I need help in this function . Here I am only able to remove one '1' why is this happening please help

```
struct Node* ptr2= head;
    struct Node* ptr3= head->next;
    while(ptr3!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr3->data==x)
        {
            ptr2->next=ptr3->next;
        }
        ptr2=ptr2->next;
        ptr3=ptr3->next;
    }
    cout<<"Number of occurance is: "<<count<<endl;
   return head;
```

```
whole program is :- 

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
void traversal(struct Node* head)
{
    cout<<"Your linked list is ";
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
        ptr=ptr->next;

    }
}
struct Node* deleterepeated(struct Node* head, int x)
{
    int s=0;//number of elements in linked list
    struct Node* p = head;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        p=p->next;
        s++;
    }
    struct Node* ptr = head;
   
    int count=0;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->data == x)
        {
            if(count==0)
            {
                head=ptr->next;
            }
            count++;
        }
    
        ptr=ptr->next;
    
    }

    struct Node* ptr2= head;
    struct Node* ptr3= head->next;
    while(ptr3!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr3->data==x)
        {
            ptr2->next=ptr3->next;
        }
        ptr2=ptr2->next;
        ptr3=ptr3->next;
    }
    cout<<"Number of occurance is: "<<count<<endl;
   return head;
}
int main()
{
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* val1;
    struct Node* val2;
    struct Node* val3;
    struct Node* val4;
    struct Node* val5;
    struct Node* val6;

    head= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    val1= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    val2= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    val3= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    val4= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    val5= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    val6= (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data=1;
    val1->data=2;
    val2->data=1;
    val3->data=2;
    val4->data=1;
    val5->data=3;
    val6->data=1;

    head->next=val1;
    val1->next=val2;
    val2->next=val3;
    val3->next=val4;
    val4->next=val5;
    val5->next=val6;
    val6->next=NULL;

    traversal(head);
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    int x;
    cin>>x;

    head=deleterepeated(head,x);
    cout<<"After deleting repeated elements: "<<endl;
    traversal(head);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are very rare circumstances where using `malloc` is a good idea in C++. Also you don't need to add `struct` on every use of a struct in C++; that's only required, if you're writing C code. Furthermore in C++ `nullptr` should be used instead of the `NULL` macro. Note that except for the use of `std::cout` the program is basically C code.

Comment: This is because the logic for removing the value from the list is wrong. You can easily see its fundamental flaws simply by considering what happens if the value to remove happens to be in the head node of the list.`ptr3` will be set to the second node in the list, and the head node will never be checked, and will not be removed. Start from scratch. Write down the algorithm first, on paper, with a pencil, using short, brief statements in plain English. Then, [discuss this algorithm with your rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), only then write any code.

Comment: the program is running fine with NULL vscode , i was asking you to correct my algorithm not my syntax

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I made a program to remove the first node too if the duplicate element is present there

Comment: ` while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->data == x)
        {
            if(count==0)
            {
                head=ptr->next;
            }
            count++;
        }
    
        ptr=ptr->next;
    
    }`

Comment: This is fundamentally flawed. It should possible to remove all particular values from the entire linked list, no matter where they are, with just one loop, about 6-7 lines of code. Have you tried [discussing this task with your rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? If I submitted something like this as my homework assignment I wouldn't expect to get a very good grade.

Comment: @Divyam *I made a program to remove the first node too* -- A separate program to do this?  What if all software companies operated the same way -- "We have a separate program to delete the first row of the spreadsheet" -- does that make sense to you?  Your program is supposed to handle all cases.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i meant I made separate cases using if else to remove the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so , you have a little tiny mistakes in your code , I edited it out , all  of the edits are in the function named `deleterepeated` and here is my solution , not the best but it will work for your case  :

**EDIT**: I removed unnecessary things in the code to be only one big loop , also I found a bug in my previous code and edit it out here in the new version , this is only the `deleterepeated` function

```
    struct Node* deleterepeated(struct Node* head, int x)
    {
        int count = 0;
        struct Node* ptr2 = head;
        struct Node* ptr3 = ptr2->next;
        struct Node* temp;
        while (ptr3 != NULL)
        {
            if (head && head->data == x)    // here is the part of deleting the head if it matches
            {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(temp);
                ptr2 = head;
                ptr3 = head->next;
            }
            else if (ptr3 && ptr3->data == x)
            {
                temp = ptr3;
                ptr2->next = ptr3->next;
                free(temp);           // you have to free memory to avoid memory leak
                ptr3 = ptr2->next;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr2 = ptr2->next;
                ptr3 = ptr3->next;
            }

        }
        cout << "Number of occurance is: " << count << endl;
        return head;
    }
```

picture of the results:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aside from the fact that it's Stackoverflow's policy not to write entire programs for other people, the entire logic is about ten times longer than it needs to be. The logic for removing a particular value from a single linked list should be no more than 6-7 lines of code, and just a single loop instead of an entire novel, that counts various things for no particular reason.

Comment: using this program the output is
Your linked list is 2 286463440 286464512 286464640 2 3

Comment: garbage values are coming

Comment: @Divyam , I am pretty sure there is no garbage values , I tried the code on the visual studio and it's working just fine , please copy the whole code not a part of it

Comment: @Divyam , you were right , I found a bug in my previous code , and edit it out and this is the new one , I only edited the function that deletes the node , that's all

Comment: yes this one worked right thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to do if you use the standard linked list implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> list{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1};
    int nOnes = 0;
    for (auto it = list.begin(), end = list.end(); it != end; /*no op*/) {
        if (*it == 1) {
            ++nOnes;
            it = list.erase(it); // remove element idiom
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Removed " << nOnes << " item(s)\n"
              << "Remains: \n";
    for (auto const e : list) {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}
```

As a side-note, it is even nicer with a vector:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1};
    auto const nOnes = vec.end() - std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);
    vec.resize(vec.size() - nOnes);
}
```